# ValueError when settign xlim in pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
stock = '^GSPC'
data = web.DataReader(stock, 'yahoo', start, end)
data['month'] = data.index.month
data['day'] = data.index.day
data.set_index('month',append=True,inplace=True)
data.set_index('day',append=True,inplace=True)
df = data.groupby(['month', 'day']).mean()
df.plot(y = 'Close');
```

The plot looks like this:

[image]

I keep getting this plot

[image]

How can i set the `xlim`?

In the official documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html this format is given:

```
DataFrame.plot(xlim = '')
```

Thus:

```
df.plot(y = 'Close', xlim =('df.index[0]', 'df.index[-1]'));
```

This plot only goes till (1,3) but the value of `df.index[-1]` is:

```
Out[74]: (12, 31)
```

How can i fix the end value of xlim?

Edit:

What i want to do is that my plot look like this:
[image]

As you can see it starts on one spine of y axis and ends at the end of the plot. There is no "whitespace" before the start and after the end. Is there anyway i can have the plot start and end without the "gap"?

Comment: It looks like your data is all plotted in the first plot. Do you by chance just need to change the xticks/labels, i.e. is this an XY problem?

Comment: @BigBen I have updated the question. I am trying to get rid of the gap which is there on the plot before it starts and after it ends.

Comment: `ax = plt.gca()`, `ax.margins(0,0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit (and not the original question), change the [`Axes.margins`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins.html):

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.margins(0)
```

or just to change the xmargin

```
ax.margins(x=0)
```